# Making certain words in a div a different style makes the paragraph break off really weird

Tags: html, css, alignment, typography

I can't figure out what's making this happen. I tried `spanning` the elements, tried making the whole thing surrounded by a `<p>` tag, tried making the object `inline-block`, you name it. I've been stuck on this for a few hours now *(yes, hours)* and it's bugging me. Taking away the class I made also doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcrdxaj6/)

```css
#intro{
margin: auto;
width: 60%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

h3{
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-size: 25px;
color: #20A6B2
}

.textNoBreak{
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">

<h2>Projekt "vidimo sE" je projekt Udruge za sindrom Down - Rijeka 21. 
Projekt je</h2>

<h3 class="textNoBreak">senzibilizacije</h3>

<h2> javnosti i</h2>

<h3 class="textNoBreak"> inkluzije</h3>


<h2>. Stoga, vidimo sE na igralištu i u školi...vidimo sE na fakultetu i na 
radnom mjestu!
</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: can you show a piece of code about how did you do the spanning ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out! It's in the answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I guess I'll leave it here in case someone finds it, it might help, right?

So, I forgot that not only h3 breaks a line, h2 does too.

What solved it is having both h3's and h2's classes set to `class="textNoBreak"` and for that styling in CSS add a property of `display:inline;`.

Makes the text all nice and fit well. Also remove `float:left;`.

Thanks anyways!

[Fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/3u3w5Lt8/1/)